# IndexError: list index out of range in comparison of a single value

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

It is a binary search problem in rotated array that I am trying to solve using recursion in python3. I calculate the middle index in List and compare it with a target value, its is giving an IndexError

```
def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        numlen=len(nums)
        mid=numlen//2
        if nums[mid]==target:
            return mid
        else:
            left=self.search(nums[:mid],target)
            if left!=-1:
                return left
            right=self.search(nums[mid:],target)
            if right!=-1:
                return right+mid
            if(left==-1 & right==-1):
                return -1
```

The expected output should be the index of the target in list and if not found should return -1, however it displaying IndexError: list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

As you're dividing the list by half in each recursion, it'll eventually become an empty list.

If the input is an empty list, any index is of course out-of-range:

```py
[1, 1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1] -> [1] -> []
```

```py
nums = []
numlen = len(nums)  # len = 0
mid = numlen // 2   # mid = 0
nums[mid]           # oops
```

To fix, you must explicitly check for an empty list, and return `-1` as "not found":

```
def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    numlen = len(nums)
    if numlen == 0:
        return -1
    mid = numlen // 2
```

Or the pythonic way to do this:

```
def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    if not nums:
        return -1
```

Comment: @Tejas You should click the grey mark to mark it as "accepted" if you find this answer helpful.